# How to stop numbers from being entered in a contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mqfntbws/

I have a `contenteditable span` in which I want to prevent users from typing special characters or numbers. The problem is, I'm able to prevent special characters but it won't work on numbers. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<span required="" contenteditable="" placeholder="First Name" aria-required="true"></span>
```

JS:

```
$('span[contenteditable]').on('keypress', function (event) {
      var regex = new RegExp("^[A-z]+$");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key) && !((event.keyCode>=46 && event.keyCode<=58) || event.keyCode==8 || event.keyCode==9 || (event.keyCode>=37 && e.keyCode<=40))) {
         console.log(">>>");
                 event.preventDefault();
                 return false;
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you appear to be using jQuery, you can make full use of the `isNumeric()` function within the API.

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/):

> The $.isNumeric() method checks whether its argument represents a numeric value. If so, it returns true. Otherwise it returns false. The argument can be of any type.

So using this cleans up your `if` statement immensely.

```
if(!regex.test(key) || $.isNumeric(key))
```

Leaving you with the following:

```
$('span[contenteditable]').on('keypress', function (event) {

    var regex = new RegExp("^[A-z]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);

    if (!regex.test(key) || $.isNumeric(key)) {

      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
});
```

I have forked and updated your original fiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/GH05T/mqfntbws/6/

Comment: Thank you! I still have to include conditions to check for Delete, backspace, tab and arrows but I guess this works for now.